Windows 10 PC cannot modify files in a shared folder on Windows Server 2008 when accessed by IP address
I have a file server running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Accessing a shared folder \\servername\share has all permissions and can be read/write from any Windows 7 PC with my domain user account.
When the folder is opened as \\IP\share from a Windows 10 PC, it opens but cant modify or create files in it. An access denied error message is displayed.
If I access \\servername\share from Windows 10, I have full access. I can modify and create files in it.
This is the same even logged in with the domain administrator account.
All office documents from this share are opening in Windows 10 pc as protected mode when accessing with IP.
Expecting advises / workarounds for this.

Upgrade your server. 2008r2 has been End Of Life for 4 years. Same goes for windows 7. In addition, Kerberos leads to different results when using IP versus hostname, so fix DNS (and domain membership) so that all clients uses same access method.

Thanks its in plan, but it is very expensive. we have 8 servers with same configuration, serving different roles in this system. need to upgrade all together. so will take some time

Well, access by hostname.
